# What is the effect of spin-orbit interaction to the band structure?

Tags: electronic-band-theory, spin-orbit

I have a question regarding the spin-orbit interaction in zinc blend materials. As far as I understood, the split-off valence band (VB) forms as a result of this interaction, and it is a shift in energy that causes the formation of the split-off band.

On the other hand, spin-orbit interaction causes a splitting of spin-up and down states in the k-space in the conduction band (CB) even without an applied magnetic field.

Are these two phenomena, the band splitting in CB and VB related? Are there any recommended references?
Thanks,

Comment: Aren't both a consequence of the diagonalization? Did you check the usual sources: R Winkler *Spin Orbit Effects...* ?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by diagonalization?

Comment: It's been a while but take something like the 8 band Kane model or a Luttinger-Kohn model and calculate the bands